# How to split Date, Month, date, hour, minute, second in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yib9Q.png)

I have a .log file with long list of datetime and would like to split them to column: year, month, date, hour, minute, second, millisecond. Following is a part of list data I need to split:

```
2015-07-15 20:51:40
2015-07-15 20:51:30
2015-07-15 20:51:20
2015-07-15 20:51:10
2015-07-15 20:51:00
2015-07-15 20:50:50
2015-07-15 20:50:49
```

But when I write the following code, it shows that and millisecond doesn't happen:

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'"

just one row works:

```
t2  int  2014
t3  int  7
t4  int  14
t5  int  21
t6  int  0
t7  int  10
```

Expected output:

```
Day Month Year Hour Minute Second Millisecond
15 07 2015 20 51 40
15 07 2015 20 51 30
15 07 2015 20 51 20
15 07 2015 20 51 10
15 07 2015 20 51 00
15 07 2015 20 50 50
15 07 2015 20 50 40
```

Here is code i used:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
dirname=askopenfilename( initialdir='/.log', title= 'please select a directory')
j=pd.read_csv(dirname, header=None, sep=r";")
t1=j[j.columns[0]]
for date_column in t1:
    date_text = datetime.strptime(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
    d = date_text
    t2 = d.year
    t3 = d.month
    t4 = d.day
    t5 = d.hour
    t6 = d.minute
    t7 = d.second
    t8 = d.millisecond
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I already fixed. Pls check if it's fine.

Comment: I adjusted one line, please verify it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, I use pandas to split them in DataFrame.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
dirname=askopenfilename( initialdir='/.log', title= 'please select a directory')
j=pd.read_csv(dirname, header=None, sep=r";")
j.drop(j.index[[2]], inplace=True)
cols = [1]
j.drop(j.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)
t1=j[j.columns[0]]
t1.drop(t1.index[[0,1]], inplace=True)
for date_column in t1:
    time_format = '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f' if '.' in date_column else '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S'
dff = pd.DataFrame(t1, columns = ['time'])
dff['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dff['time'])
t2 = dff['time'].dt.year.astype(str).tolist()
t3 = dff['time'].dt.month.astype(str).tolist()
t4 = dff['time'].dt.day.astype(str).tolist()
t5 = dff['time'].dt.hour.astype(str).tolist()
t6 = dff['time'].dt.minute.astype(str).tolist()
t7 = dff['time'].dt.second.astype(str).tolist()
t8 = dff['time'].dt.microsecond.astype(int)
t9 = [int(x) for x in t8/1000]
t99 = list(map(str, t9))
```

Answer (score 0):

`parser.parse()` is expecting a `str` but you giving it a `list`.  You need something like:

```
for date_column in t1:
    date_text = parser.parse(date_column)
    # do something with date_text
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried and my code is better, but the splitted date just happened for the first row. Can you help me separate for the whole column?. The photo of column had been attached as image description.Currently, code change to: 
    for date_column in t1:
    d = parser.parse(date_column)
    t2 = d.year
    t3 = d.month
    t4 = d.day
    t5 = d.hour
    t6 = d.minute
    t7 = d.second